# How can I display additional order information on checkout page through cart?

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I need to display additional order information on checkout page through cart page.

Can any one help me for this.

Answer (score 2):

You can add additional order information on checkout page through cart attribute.

For this add below code in shopify **cart.liquid** file between the **`<form>` and `</form>`** tag. The form field will appear wherever you place the code.

```
<p class="cart-attribute__field">
  <label for="your-name">Your name</label>
  <input id="your-name" type="text" name="attributes[Your name]" value="{{ cart.attributes["Your name"] }}">
</p>
```

You can also check this link : [https://ui-elements-generator.myshopify.com/pages/cart-attribute](http://Cart%20attribute)

Answer (score 0):

Use `{{ cart.attributes["Your name"] }}` on your `checkout.liquid` to display the desired option.